# Non-numerical value for a derivative on NDSolve function

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following system of differential equations:

```
eqn1 = m1 x1''[t] + k1 (x1[t] - x2[t]) + c1 (x1'[t] - x2'[t]) == 0;
eqn2 = m2 x2''[t] + k1 (x2[t] - x1[t]) + c1 (x2'[t] - x1'[t]) + k2 (x2[t]) + c2 (x2'[t])
==c2*(1.09013 Cos[Pi*13.88*t]) + k2*(0.025 Sin[Pi*13.88*t]);
```

To solve them I am using the following code for `NDSolve`:

```
ivals = {x1[0] == 0, x1'[0] == 0, x2[0] == 0, x2'[0] == 0};
soln = NDSolve[{{eqn1, eqn2}, ivals}, {x1[t], x2[t]}, {t, 0, 10}];
```

When I try to solve this I get the following error message:

> NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0

And I don't understand why.

I would very much appreciate some help.

Comment: Try another set of initial conditions; right now x1[t]=x2[t]=0 is a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this answers your question but…

```
eqn1 = x1''[t] == - (x1[t] - x2[t]) - (x1'[t] - x2'[t]);
eqn2 = x2''[t] == -k1 (x2[t] - x1[t]) - (x2'[t] - x1'[t]) + - (x2[t]);
```

Then

```
 ivals = {x1[0] == 1, x1'[0] == 0, x2[0] == 1, x2'[0] == 0};
 sol = DSolve[Flatten@{{eqn1, eqn2}, ivals} // Evaluate, {x1[t], x2[t]}, t]
```

works…

So would this if you want symbolic `m1,m2,c1,c2`

```
eqn1 = m1 x1''[t] == - k1 (x1[t] - x2[t]) - c1  (x1'[t] - x2'[t]);
eqn2 = m2 x2''[t] == -k1 (x2[t] - x1[t]) -  c2 (x2'[t] - x1'[t]) + - (x2[t]);
```